# How to control margin around mpl_toolkits basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm drawing a map, saving it to a file, and getting unexpected margins (white space) around all sides of the map. I want the map to completely fill the image with no margin, or as little margin as possible.

Here is the code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), edgecolor='k')
m = Basemap(projection="cyl", resolution="l", llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90, llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180)
m.shadedrelief(alpha=0.5)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5, color="gray")
plt.savefig("map.pdf")
```

This is the resulting image -- I've manually shaded the margin to make it visible:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the export format, what does it do with "map.png"?

Comment: Thanks Jean. Unfortunately, it is the same result for both png and pdf.

Comment: Hmm, can you try using [plt.margins](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html)`plt.margins(0)` (Sorry I cannot try it myself right now)

Comment: plt.margins did not work, but your comment reminded me of something else to try: fig.tight_layout().  Tight layout fixed the problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome ^^

Answer (score 1):

Tight layout removed the margins.  This is the updated code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), edgecolor='k')
m = Basemap(projection="cyl", resolution="l", llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90, llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180)
m.shadedrelief(alpha=0.5)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5, color="gray")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("map.png")
```